# Pure States of Multi-Matrix Algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $$A=\bigoplus_{j=1}^mM_{n_j}(\mathbb{C}).$$

> **Question 1:** Is it true that every state on $A$ is of the form:
>   $$\rho=\bigoplus_{j=1}^m \rho_{j},$$
>
> where each $\rho_j$ is a positive functional on $M_{n_j}(\mathbb{C})$?

Isn't this obviously true... or am I missing something? More importantly for me:

> **Question 2:** Moreover, either as a corollary or a separate result, is each pure
>   state of $A$ equal to zero on every factor except for one? i.e. each pure state on $A$ arises from a pure state on one of the matrix factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 2, yes. For question 1, almost yes, every state is of the form
$$\rho=\bigoplus^{m}_{j=1}\lambda_{j}\rho_{j}$$
where $\rho_{j}$ is a state on $M_{n_{j}}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\lambda_{j}\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that $\sum^{m}_{j=1}\lambda_{j}=1$. This to ensure that
$$\rho(I_{A})=\sum^{m}_{j=1}\lambda_{j}\rho_{j}(I_{n_{j}})=\sum^{m}_{j=1}\lambda_{j}\rho_{j}=1.$$

Comment: Thank you. In fairness I knew it was a convex combination so I wrote that $\rho_j$ were positive functionals.

Comment: True, but taking arbitrary positive functionals would not automatically yield a state.