# Pure State Definition Confusion

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, dual-spaces

Let me start with some objects. Consider the $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $A$ defined by:
$$A=M_1(\mathbb{C})\oplus M_2(\mathbb{C})\subset B(\mathbb{C}^3).$$
Let $x=\mathbb{C}^3$ be given by $(e_1+e_2)/\sqrt{2}\,$  (the one dimensional factor acts on $e_1$).

We have a vector state given by $\rho_x(f)=\langle x,f(x)\rangle$, and

$$\rho_x\left((c_1)+\left(\begin{array}{cc}c_{11} & c_{12} \\ c_{21} & c_{22}\end{array}\right)\right)=\frac12 c_1+\frac{1}{2}c_{11}.$$

If I read something about quantum mechanics for such a state, as it is is given by a unit vector, it is called a pure state.

However this contradicts [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3273820/19352) to this question... and when I pick up Murphy he says that a pure state is such that if $\rho_0\leq \rho_x$ is a positive linear functional, then $\rho_0=t\rho_x$ for $t\in[0,1]$.

However for $\rho_x$ we have the linear functional:

$$\rho_0\left((c_1)+\left(\begin{array}{cc}c_{11} & c_{12} \\ c_{21} & c_{22}\end{array}\right)\right)=\frac12 c_1$$

is a bounded linear functional such that $\rho_x-\rho_{0}$ is a positive linear functional --- half the state given by the vector $e_2$, not $t\rho_x$... and so Murphy would say $\rho_x$ is *not* pure.

**Can you help me with my confusion?**

Comment: I suspect that the unit-vector characterization of pure states only holds if the $C^*$-algebra under consideration is $M_k(\Bbb C)$

Comment: More generally, vector states are pure if the $C^\ast$-algebra acts irreducibly, which is not the case for $A$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann OK, it sounds like the QM bits I am reading are working on full $B(\mathsf{H})$ rather than subalgebras of same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\pi :A\to B(H)$ is any non-degenerate representation of the C*-algebra $A$,  and if $x$ is a unit vector in $H$, then the state
$$
  \varphi (a) = \langle x,\pi(a)x\rangle
  $$
is pure iff the cyclic space
$$
  [\pi (A)x] = \overline{\text{span}}\{\pi (a) x: a\in A\}
  $$
is irreducible for the action of $A$ there.

This is because the representation of $A$ on  $[\pi (A)x]$ is equivalent to the GNS representation associated to $\varphi $, and
it is well known that a GNS representation is irreducible iff the state is pure.

In the example given,  one can show that $[Ax]=\mathbb C^3$, which is not irreducible,  so $\rho _x$ is not pure.

On the other hand,
as noted by @MaoWao,
if $A$ is an irreducible algebra of operators on $H$, such as $B(H)$ itself,    $[\pi (A)x] = H$, for every unit vector
$x$, whence every vector state is pure.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is that the (introductory) quantum mechanical texts that I am reading are using the full $B(\mathsf{H})$ rather than closed self-adjoint subalgebras.

For example in full $B(\mathbb{C}^3)$, the state associated to the same vector is:

$$\rho_x\left([c_{ij}]_{i,j=1}^3\right)=\frac{c_{11}+c_{12}+c_{21}+c_{22}}{2},$$
a different beast to $\rho_x\in A^*$.